# remove table rows before reload

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to remove all rows in my table view before reloading the data, but can't seem to get it to work.

In my viewcontroller I get my array from this AFNetworking request.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" 
                                     parameters:nil 
                                        success:
                ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                    NSMutableArray *location_results = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for (id locationDictionary in response) {
                       Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
                       [location_results addObject:location];  
                    }
                    self.location_results = location_results;
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }
                                    failure:
                ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                }];  
}
```

And I want to remove data then reload it with this button

```
- (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender {

    [[Location sharedSingleton].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *location_results = [NSMutableArray array];
    [location_results removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

But it's not removing the rows. I see the reload happening over the top of the rows that are already there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **DON'T EVER** call `viewDidLoad` manually.

Create a method like

```
- (void)reloadDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *locations))completion
                         failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure {
    [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" 
                                     parameters:nil 
                                        success:
            ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                NSMutableArray *location_results = [NSMutableArray array];
                for (id locationDictionary in response) {
                   Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
                   [location_results addObject:location];  
                }
                    if(completion)
                        completion(location_results);
                }
                                failure:
            ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                if(failure)
                    failure(error);
            }];  
}
```

And call it whenever you need to reload the data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; // Don't forget the call to super!

    [self reloadDataWithCompletion:^(NSArray *locations) {
        self.location_results = locations;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}

- (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender {
    [[Location sharedSingleton].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self reloadDataWithCompletion:^(NSArray *locations) {
        self.location_results = locations;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
```

In order to achieve a graphical effect for reloading the table you can do (assuming that you have only one section), substitute

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

with

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele, this is very helpful. Where should I call removeAllObjects? Implementing your suggestions still does not clear out the table view before reloading.

Comment: @jacobt it depends on what do you want to achieve? Do you want a graphical effect of disappearing? Or simply reload the whole table?

Comment: I would like the graphical effect of disappearing when the button is pressed followed by reloading the table cells with new data. Is it possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this is not removing the rows, it adds several layers of table cells in the first row after hitting locationPressed several times.

Comment: what it should do is to reload all the row with an animation. I don't understand what do you mean by "*it adds several layers*"

Comment: The first row has several cells stacked on top of each other. The other rows also don't clear and reload with animation as you expected. I'll keep working on it and I appreciate your help but let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.